# Error while renaming files with os.rename() in Python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("C:/Users/Awesome/Music"):
    if filename.endswith("lyrics.mp3"):
        os.rename(filename,filename[0 : len(filename)-11]+".mp3")
```

The code above returns the error

```
File "c:/python/lyrics-pop.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.rename(filename,filename[0 : len(filename)-11]+".mp3")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '2 Chainz - Bigger Than You (feat Drake  Quavo) lyrics.mp3' -> '2 Chainz - Bigger Than You (feat Drake  Quavo).mp3'
```

"""

I have made sure that no other program is accessing the .mp3 files and removed the readonly attribute. What could be causing this?

Comment: If you check the filename, you will see that it doesn't have the path, so you will need to append the folder path and the filename to extract the actual file. Use os.path.join.

Comment: okay lemme try that, thanks

Comment: You can also use `glob`, which will give you the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the issue is that you are passing relative path to os.rename, add dir to file path, like this:

```
import os
dir = "C:/Users/Awesome/Music"
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith("lyrics.mp3"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir,filename),os.path.join(dir,filename[0 : len(filename)-11])+".mp3")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because python can not find the file from where this program is running, since full path is not given.

You can do it as follows:

```
import os
filedir = "C:/Users/Awesome/Music"
for filename in os.listdir(filedir):
    if filename.endswith("lyrics.mp3"):
        filepath = os.path.join(filedir, filename)
        new_file = os.path.join(filedir, filename[0 : len(filename)-11]+".mp3")
        os.rename(filepath, new_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the problem seems to be the relative path of the files.
You can use `glob`, which will give you the full path, i.e.:

```
from glob import glob
from os import rename

for f in glob("C:/Users/Awesome/Music/*lyrics.mp3"):
    rename(f, f[0 : len(f)-11]+".mp3")
```